# What is my output size for my Keras Embedding layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, data-science

I can't seem to find the correct Keras output dim size for my model. How do you calculate this?

```
top_words = 2000
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(num_words=top_words)
# pad dataset to a maximum review length in words
max_words = 30
X_train = sequence.pad_sequences(X_train, maxlen=max_words)
X_test = sequence.pad_sequences(X_test, maxlen=max_words)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(top_words, 32))
model.add(LSTM(128, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2)) 
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')) 


model.compile(optimizer='adam',
            loss='binary_crossentropy',
            metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I'll get an error code like this indices[2,22] = 55 is not in [0, 30)

The size of x test and train is 25000,3

I tried several different sizes, but guessing doesn't seem to work. How do you calculate this?

Comment: The error is not related to `Keras Model` the error is telling you that on `index[2,22]` it contain the token 55, which is not in the max-length. Increase your `max-length`.